UART only succesfull on first transmit
I have a STM32 NUCLEO-L031K6 board that I am trying to test some UART on.
Following this guide: https://wiki.st.com/stm32mcu/wiki/STM32StepByStep:Step3_Introduction_to_the_UART
I get TeraTerm to show "Hello World !!!" 1 time, and then just repeatedly "He". If i push the reset-button on the board, it shows "Hello World !!!" only once again and the goes on with "He".
TeraTerm has the correct settings I think.

This is the code from the guide I am using:
uint8_t Test[] = "Hello World !!!\r\n"; //Data to send
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,Test,sizeof(Test),10);// Sending in normal mode
      HAL_Delay(1000);

I am fairly new to both C-language and the embedded world.
Do you have any tips on what I could do to fix this, or some documentation I might have missed?

sizeof(Test) is usually not the way to go since it also means sending the null terminator over UART. Which might in turn confuse terminal programs. I don't think that's the cause of this problem, but it's probably a bug. Do sizeof(Test)-1 instead.

It rather sounds as if your MCU is stuck rebooting or maybe your busy-wait delay isn't working. Check if you have the watchdog enabled and if so, how often you need to feed it. Does single stepping through the program with your debugger solve the problem?

You can also use char mystr[100]="test string";
In that case you reserve more space for future operations but initialise with "test string". strlen(mystr) returns the proper length.

Try some other terminal or some other  mode for terminal emulation. This does not determine if the problem is the terminal end getting confused about the extra NUL or the STM32 really having a problem other than sending out an extra NUL.
